# Crystal Report definir tamanho texto do valor em um gráfico

Tags: asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

estou usando o Crystal Report versão 13 em uma aplicação com Aspnet Webforms. Estou desenvolvendo relatórios com gráficos e exibindo o valor dos "rótulos de dados".

Meu problema é que não consigo modificar o tamanho da fonte desses valores, já alterei todas propriedades de fonte do gráfico porém nenhuma refletiu no rótulo de dados.

Também explorei todas propriedades do relatório e não obtive êxito. As fontes no tamanho padrão não estão ficando com a exibição boa por causa da massa de dados, logo minha necessidade é diminuir o tamanho da fonte.

Importante frisar que o relatório possui vários sub-relatórios, os gráficos estão dentro dos sub-relatórios.

OBS> "rótulo de dados" é o valor exibido após (ou dentro) de cada linha no gráfico.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Em cada subreport faça : Banco de Dados /Verificar Banco de Dados forçando os parâmetros para que os valores cheguem ao máximo.

Comment: Já tive problemas com os gráficos do Crystal-reports tbm, mas como estava sem tempo, tive que recorrer a uma gambiarra. Criei o HTML no servidor, gerei uma imagem e enviei para o Crystal, hehe...